# integration of a complex function having many terms

Tags: calculus

I have a function that is $$f(x) = x^2 \sin^2\left(x^2\log\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)$$

here log is in base 10.

How to start of it to get a simplified step?

I tried taking $\log(1/x)=t$ and also tried one more substituion after this but there I got stuck.

Please help me solve this problem.

Comment: From Wolfram Alpha, it looks like there is no elementary antiderivative.

Comment: In the majority of cases, integrals won't have an elementary anti-derivative. It's often obvious when the integral looks like a composition of many functions, transcendental, trigonometric or otherwise. Intuition often tells you this is the case but Wolfram Alpha is a good check.